# Java - Will synchronize on a function block access to instance properties?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety, synchronized

if I have

```
class A {
    public int a;
    public synchronized void myMethod() {
       Thread.sleep(1000) 
    }
}
```

If a thread is running `myMethod` will `a` property be blocked for access and modification for other threads on that A instance?

Comment: Only if you made `a` private and restricted access of `a` to synchronized getter/setter methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question succinctly: no, it won't block other threads from accessing/modifying properties.

Verbose answer: `synchronized` is a key part of Java's threading mechanism. It is how threads wait for each other. You should also see Object.wait and Object.notify/.notifyAll . Synchronized is about thread execution control, not about data leakage.

Comment: Yes I was confusing myself, I thought synchronized locked the whole instance, but it only locks it to the methods that are syncrhonized, even if they are not the same.

Comment: Re, "`synchronized`...is how threads wait for each other." IMO that's misleading. I've seen more than a few questions from newbies who were trying to use `synchronized` or `ReentrantLock`, when they should have been using `wait()` and `notify()` or some higher-level synchronization object. I would say, `synchronized` is how threads keep out of each other's way. `wait()` and `notify()` and higher-level things built on `wait()` and `notify()` are how threads cooperate with each other.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I get your point and I agree with you, though I would prefer "... more accurately be described as..." than "misleading"... Unless you think I am trying to mislead people on SO :)

Comment: OK, That's fair. IMO, `synchronized` could be more accurately described as ... (what I said, above).